# Browserify: import react module

Tags: reactjs, browserify, babeljs

I started using react recently and i'd like to include in my project third  party component. I installed it in my project with npm (dir node-modules was created), my index.html look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React Calendar</title>
    <script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My index.js look like this:

```
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';

BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment);

ReactDOM.render(<BigCalendar
    events={myEventsList}
    startAccessor='startDate'
    endAccessor='endDate'
/>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

I tried the command:

```
browserify index.js -o bundle.js
```

but it gave me this error:

```
C:\Users\ernest\PhpstormProjects\reactcalendar\index.js:1
import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

so I tried to install babelify and tried this commad:

```
browserify -t babelify index.js -o bundle.js
```

but it gave me this another error:

```
SyntaxError: C:/Users/ernest/PhpstormProjects/reactcalendar/index.js: Unexpected token (8:16)
   6 | BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment); // or globalizeLocalizer
   7 |
>  8 | ReactDOM.render(<BigCalendar
     |                 ^
   9 |     events={myEventsList}
  10 |     startAccessor='startDate'
  11 |     endAccessor='endDate'
    at Parser.pp.raise (C:\Users\ernest\PhpstormProjects\reactcalendar\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\location.js:22:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\Users\ernest\PhpstormProjects\reactcalendar\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\util.js:89:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (C:\Users\ernest\PhpstormProjects\reactcalendar\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:522:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (C:\Users\ernest\PhpstormProjects\reactcalendar\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:277:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (C:\Users\ernest\PhpstormProjects\reactcalendar\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:257:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (C:\Users\ernest\PhpstormProjects\reactcalendar\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:188:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (C:\Users\ernest\PhpstormProjects\reactcalendar\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:165:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (C:\Users\ernest\PhpstormProjects\reactcalendar\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:128:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprListItem (C:\Users\ernest\PhpstormProjects\reactcalendar\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:1046:16)
    at Parser.pp.parseCallExpressionArguments (C:\Users\ernest\PhpstormProjects\reactcalendar\node_modules\babelify\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:353:20)
```

In my node-modules dir is installed:

- babelify
- moment
- react
- react-big-calendar
- react-dom

So my question is: How can i create my budle.js from index.js using import statement?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Babel does not handle the React JSX syntax.

You need to tell Babel to use a [JSX preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/), to translate these into normal JS calls:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-react
```

Then create a file named `.babelrc` ([reference](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/)) with the following contents

```
{
  "presets": ["react"]
}
```

Comment: Thank you but now it gave me the first error again (`ParseError: 'import' and {...}`), I tried to add a file `package.json` to my root project with the following contents: 
`{
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify"
    ]
  }
}`
but it gave me the same error! Maybe i have to add something else on the `.babelrc`?

Comment: Oh, try setting `presets` to `["es2015", "react"]`?

Comment: Ok, now it seems to work! But it gave me this error:
`Error: Cannot find module 'react-big-calendar' from 'C:\Users\ernest\PhpstormProjects\reactcalendar'`
Some ideas?

Comment: Do you have `react-big-calendar` in your package.json? Is it installed into `node_modules`? If both are true, then it must be a browserify issue... It could be better to use a solution like Webpack or Brunch, as a general aside.

Comment: `package.json` look like this:
`{
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.10.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.10.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
}`
`react-big-calendar` is installed.

Comment: i tried with webpack, my `webpack.config.js` look like this:
`module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,

    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ["babel-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]",
            }
        ]
    },

    entry: {
        javascript: "./index.js",
        html: "./index.html"
    }
}`

Comment: but it gave me the same error of browserify... Maybe i wrong something with the config file of webpack?